# Django-TinyMCE How to render Django template tags in TinyMCE?

Tags: python, django-templates, tinymce, templatetags, django-tinymce

Is there any way to render django template tags/variables inside the Django-TinyMCE editor? As in:

1. "{% url 'url-name' %}" inside the link plugin.
2. "{{ model.get_absolute_url }}" inside the link plugin.

Any help is appreciated,